# nokia PC suite hangs during installation

Tags: windows-xp, installation, nokia-pc-suite

I installed Nokia PC Suite on my computer, only to find that the version doesn't support my cell phone.  I promptly uninstalled it, but the uninstall got stuck, and I killed it.  Subsequent attempts to install the correct version failed because of the previous install that was still pending.

I ran Windows XP recovery to restore the settings to a point before the initial installation, and tried again.  Now the installation hangs at 88% of the install.  I left it overnight and it was still at 88% in the morning.  I killed the install and reran the restore, and tried again, and it keeps on getting stuck at 88%.

Any ideas how I can get the install to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has the installation software already created folders on Program Files? If so, you may need to delete them as well as any other temporary folders it has created. I'd suggest running [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) if you have that. (If you don't, I've provided the link here for you.)

Another thing to consider is the PC Suite installer itself. Did you download it from the Nokia website or are you using a CD to install? If you obtained this from the web, it's possible that it might not have been completely downloaded, which is why it's causing the process to hang at some point.